# sort NSString from a plist 1-10

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, plist

I have a problem with a plist that I want to sort. It's a highscore that I want to sort on the players ranking. The problem is that the ranking is a string, which screws up the sorting (I get 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

I somehow need to sort it the correct way. For sorting I use:

```
NSArray *unSortedNames = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL: plistURL];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"rating" ascending:YES] autorelease];
names = [[unSortedNames sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]] retain];
```

The log for the first three players looks like this:

> ```
>   {
>     isUser = NO;
>     nick = Player;
>     rating = 1;
>     score = 57314;
> },
>     {
>     isUser = NO;
>     nick = Player321;
>     rating = 10;
>     score = 212;
> },
>     {
>     isUser = NO;
>     nick = "Player123";
>     rating = 2;
>     score = 24540;
> },
> ```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks Mikael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options...

1. Add a readonly property to your class that returns an integer version of your rating iVar. Then sort based on this property.
2. Use `sortedArrayUsingFunction:` and write a function that compares 2 rankings, based on their integer values, and returns the sort order.

1 seems like it should be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! But right now I feel stupid and cannot figure out how to make an iVar of rating from the unSortedNames...

Comment: Hmm, I see, each score is a dictionary, not a class of yours... I notice that you have quotes around player 3's name, but not around the other 2... do you have quotes around your scores by any chance?

Comment: Oh, that was just a name that contained a space like: "First Last". I just changed the names to 'playerXXX' for not revealing the real names that I work with. Otherwise, no other quotes.

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised that without quotes, the rankings are being treated as strings instead of ints. Try out the second option then... you write a simple c function that takes 2 parameters and returns an int, which is -1 if the first parameter was less than the second, 0 if they were equal, and 1 if the first parameter was greater than the second.

Comment: Yes, I tried using this: http://www.paulofierro.com/archives/562/ But I'm no c-person :) And can't get it to work. Don't know what I shall send as 'context'. If I try @"rating" I get an error... Really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I don't think you need to use the context in your c function in this case... just send `self` or even try `nil`. In your c function, p1 and p2 should be dictionaries, and you can get the rating from them the same as you would normally.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time with this! But I still cannot get it to work. If I send `self` I get an error at `SEL methodselector`and if I use `nil`I get an error at `id obj1` and `methodSelector`is <null selector>. Do I need to change anything in the `compareObjectsUsingNumericalStringId`-method?

Comment: I don't think you need the methodselector at all. In the c function, you'd basically have `int first = [[p1 objectForKey:@"rating"] intValue];` and repeat for p2... then compare your 2 ints.

Comment: Thank you! Finally! I wish I could Up-vote you twice, because, right now you are my favorite developer! :) I really could need a crash course in C.